# Why do I still get the model_name error when locals present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to render my dog form in another view in my `PetsController.index`:

```
def index
  @page_title = "Add Pets"
  @title = "Add Pets"
end
```

But I get the error:

```
NoMethodError in Pets#index

Showing C:/testapp/app/views/dogs/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

1: <%= form_for @dog do |f| %>
```

pets/index.html.erb

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
   <%= render "global/flash_message" %>
   <%= render :partial => "dogs/form", :locals => {:dog => @dog } %>
</div>
```

I know I can do:

```
def index
  @page_title = "Add Pets"
  @title = "Add Pets"
  @dog = Dog.new
end
```

But what's the point of the local then? What's missing so I can use it from the `DogsController` instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `@dog` is not assigned in your `#index` action, then you're assigning `nil` to your `dog` local in the call to `render :partial`. You could leave the instance assignment out of the action and do it in your index view (i.e. `:locals => {:dog => Dog.new}`, but it has to happen somewhere.

Comment: +1, or you could do it in the form like so `<%= form_for Dog.new do |f| %>` and then forget about the locals altogether

Comment: Except if one wants to reuse the same `_form` partial for the edit page, you want to use an existing instance, not a new one.